# Permutations with repetition with IEnumerable based on integers

Tags: c#, permutation, ienumerable

I'm trying to make an IEnumerable permutations(with repetition) function on C#.
I already have a function which is using Arrays;

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermsWithReps<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
{           
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (count == 1)
        {
            yield return new T[] { item };
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var result in GetPermsWithReps(items, count - 1))
            {
                yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works pretty well... but
Now I need to make IEnumerable function that will work straight on integers, not on array. So as example if I call it like;

```
GetPermsInts(max_val = 1, digits_num = 2)
```

I should get output;

```
00
01
10
11
```

I tried to modify that function on many ways to achieve that, but no luck still...
Please could someone help me?

Comment: So you need to figure out how to, given a value, create a sequence of all of the possible values between zero and that number.  You could look through the existing LINQ methods to see if there is a method that does this (hint: there is a method that does *exactly* this) or you could write your own; it's not a terribly complex function to write.

Comment: @Servy Actually, I can write a function that will dump all of the possible values - BUT the problem is I don't want them all, I just want to get each record seperately and stop it when 3 OF THESE records match some condition - so that's why I'm using IEnumerable(because I can check record after each cycle), and don't want to use array as base parameter there anymore(because then I would have to dump all possible digits to array first, which is waste of time and memory). Do You have any ideas ?

Comment: Creating a sequence with `0` and `1` in it when you're then going to create a sequence that contains all of the permutations of that sequence with itself, is not expensive.  You're performing an operation with `n!` complexity; creating an input sequence of size `n` will never be significant in comparison.

Comment: items = Enumerable.Range(0, max_val); done. Assuming 0<=max_val <=9

Comment: @Servy The 0/1 dump was just example, I may need even up to 5 digits_num with max_digit=9. I'm not sure(didn't checked that) but it probably will take some time to dump all of permutations and I want to avoid that

Comment: @LOLOLOLO Creating a sequence of 0 to 5 is *also* not expensive, and it's nothing in comparison to the cost of computing the permutations.  It's entirely negligible in comparison.  As for not computing the permutations, your question literally just asks how to compute the permutations; if that's not what you want to do, then you didn't ask the right question.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I didn't precise maybe... But it will actually look for unique chars(or set of some chars) from (char)33 to (char)255(ASCII length). So 255-33=222. So for each field I could have 222 combinations - so imagine if I want to generate list of all combinations on five fields - then it will be 222^5 which is 539.218.609.632 combinations... It is an very extreme case which probably will be never used in my app, but it 
theoretically could have place also(note that even 3-4 fields is still generate very big list).. So is it now make sense for You to avoid it?

Comment: So you're asking how to compute the permutations of a set, and in response to finding out, you say that you can't do it.  I don't doubt that computing the permutations of that set is unreasonable, but that's what your questions asks how to do.

Comment: @Servy So that's why I just want to 'QUIT' this permutate process when 3 unique characters is found in the given string - not loop over and over to achieve all possible records which I will not need even. Any ideas how to convert that "GetPermsWithReps" function I wrote above to the function which is still Iterable but don't need array?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like that (assuming you want to return strings) :

```
IEnumerable<string> EnumeratePermutations(int digits, int length)
{
    var data = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = '0';
    }

    while (true)
    {
        yield return new string(data);

        char maxChar = (char)('0' + digits);

        for (int index = length - 1; index >= 0; --index)
        {
            if (++data[index] == maxChar)
            {
                for (int i = index; i < data.Length; ++i)
                {
                    data[i] = '0';
                }

                if (index == 0)
                {
                    yield break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way you can get any permutation of a given `length` using `digits` distinct characters. If you want a base greater than 9, then, you should probably add some mapping to use the desired characters.

This code would only generate used permutation in lexical order.

Comment: By the way, with that code, I can do `EnumeratePermutations(222, 5).Skip(35000000).Take(5)` in about 1 second on my computer. Thus I iterate about 35 millions values per second if I do nothing else with those parameters that were given in a comment below the question.